# Repeat lambda function n times in Python, wrong value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I am trying to write a program that is supposed to repeatedly smooth a value raised to 2, called using `smoothing_five_times = repeatedly_smooth(lambda x: x**2, 5)`, where the second argument is n amount of times.

```
def repeatedly_smoothed(func, n):
    return repeat(lambda x: ((func(x-0.001) + func(x) + func(x+0.001)) / 3), n)

def repeat(f, n):
    if n==0:
        return (lambda x: x)
    return (lambda x: f (repeat(f, n-1)(x)))
```

It works just fine for n = 1, but for higher x the values get out of hand.

```
smooth_one_times(10)
100.00000066666666
smooth_two_times(10)
10000.000134
```

The second one is supposed to return 100.0000013 and I just can't seem to get it to work. Dividing the repeatedly_smoothed one by 10, n or pretty much anything just gets the value farther away from what I want it to be. What beginner mistake is it that I am making?

Comment: You put in 10, you get 100.  If you recurse, you are putting in 100, and should get out 10000, which is what you reported.  So i am unsure what you are trying to do....

Comment: What are `smooth_one_times` and `smooth_two_times`?

Comment: `repeat` itself seems to be just fine.

Comment: smooth_one_times = repeatedly_smooth(lambda x: x**2, 1), smooth_two_times = repeatedly_smooth(lambda x: x**2, 2) and so on. What I am trying to do is alter the repeatedly_smoothed function to alter the output depending on n, ex:

Comment: To add a divided by 3*10**n or something akin to that to the repeatedly_smoothed function, but due to the lambda nature I don't get how to make it return 100,xxxx on each recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `smooth` as follows:

```
def smooth(f, x):
    return (f(x-0.001) + f(x) + f(x+0.001))/3
```

then I think what you *want* is for `smooth_two_times` to be equivalent to:

```
In [1]: smooth(lambda y: smooth(lambda x: x**2, y), 10)
Out[1]: 100.0000013333333
```

However, it's actually equivalent to:

```
repeatedly_smoothed(square, 2)(10)
=> repeat(lambda x: smooth(square, x), 2)(10)
=> smooth_square(repeat(smooth_square, 1)(10))
=> smooth_square(smooth_square(10))
=> smooth_square(100.00000066666666)
=> smooth_square(10000.000134)
```

where we've used the definitions:

```
def square(x): return x**2
def smooth_square(y): return smooth(square, y)
```

The problem is that `smooth_square` is a smoothed version of the square function, and you don't want to apply it twice iteratively (which will more or less square the square of 10).  Instead, you want to apply only the smoothing twice iteratively to the square function.

If you want to use your `repeat` to accomplish this, you can define `smooth_function` as follows:

```
def smooth_function(f):
    def smooth_f(x):
        return (f(x-0.001) + f(x) + f(x+0.001))/3
    return smooth_f
```

This is a higher-order function that smooths a given function (i.e., returns a smoothed version of the function).  Therefore:

```
smooth_function(smooth_function(lambda x: x**2))
```

would be a doubly-smoothed version of the quadratic function which could be applied to 10.  But, this double application of `smooth_function` can be rewritten as:

```
(repeat(smooth_function, 2))(lambda x: x**2)
```

That it, the `repeat` constructs a high order function that takes a single function as its argument and constructs a doubly-smoothed version.  It can then be applied to the value `10` to give:

```
In [2]: ((repeat(smooth_function, 2))(lambda x: x**2))(10)
Out[2]: 100.0000013333333
```

Most of the parentheses here are redundant, so you can define:

```
def repeatedly_smoothed(f, n):
    return repeat(smooth_function, n)(f)
def smooth_two_times(x):
    return repeatedly_smoothed(lambda y: y**2, 2)(x)
```

and get:

```
In [3]: smooth_two_times(10) 
Out[3]: 100.0000013333333
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what what exactly `smooth_one_times` and `smooth_two_times` are. But I'll show you my (original) definitions:

```
def smooth_one_time(k):
    return repeatedly_smoothed(lambda x: x ** 2, 1)(k)

def smooth_two_time(k):
    return repeatedly_smoothed(lambda x: x ** 2, 2)(k)
```

If you do the following instead (you're just not normalizing properly), I think you'll get what you desire:

```
def smooth_one_time(k):
    return repeatedly_smoothed(lambda x: x ** 2, 1)(k) / repeat(lambda x: x**2, 1)(10) * 100

def smooth_two_time(k):
    return repeatedly_smoothed(lambda x: x ** 2, 2)(k) / repeat(lambda x: x**2, 2)(10) * 100
```

The second definition of `smooth_two_time(10)` outputs `100.00000134` as desired. Both definitions of `smooth_one_time` are mathematically equivalent since `repeat(lambda x: x**2, 1)(10) * 100 == 1`, but I included it for pedagogical reasons and in hopes you'd see the general pattern. In case it's not clear, it generalizes nicely to this:

```
def smooth_n_times(n, k):
    return repeatedly_smoothed(lambda x: x ** 2, n)(k) / repeat(lambda x: x ** 2, n)(10) * 100
```

However, be careful. This overflows VERY quickly. `smooth_n_times(8, 10)` outputs `100.00008576`. `smooth_n_times(9, 10)` overflows on my machine.

HTH.